# How to efficiently write pandas melt and join in order to run inside containers without causing SystemOOM exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, docker, kubernetes, airflow

I have a code which is running inside a docker container, on kubernetes cluster. The issue is that regardless of the memory limit set, sometimes, the code just fails, i.e. airflow task running the code gets failed.

I tried checking in on memory and CPU utilization. Both of them are under limits and pod never restarts. Note: my pod has only one container running and that is airflow's worker. It should be noted that CPU utilization reaches "tending to 1" and the task fails.

Since the dataset is transformed correctly, I am not posting the sample data. I am looking for efficiency in terms of resources.

My code is:

```
# Below code is required at the start of each script
from athena.api import get_pandas_df
import pandas as pd

last_correct_constant = 11


def remove_unwanted_cols(df, col_name):
    unwanted_cols = []
    for _col in df.columns:
        if _col.startswith("unnamed"):
            if int(_col.split("unnamed__")[-1]) > last_correct_constant:
                unwanted_cols.append(_col)
        else:
            if not _col.startswith(col_name):
                unwanted_cols.append(_col)
    df = df.drop(columns=unwanted_cols)
    return df


def sanitize_column_names(df):
    corrected_columns = []
    for column in df.columns:
        corrected_columns.append(
            column
            .replace("(", "_")
            .replace(")", "_")
            .replace(" ", "_")
            .replace("/", "_")
            .replace(".", "_")
            .replace(":", "_")
            .lower())
    df.columns = corrected_columns
    return df


def get_first_row_as_header(df):
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    print("Columns are: ")
    print(df.columns)
    print("Head is: ")
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    print(df.head(1))
    return df


def remove_cols_for_join(df, col_name):
    unwanted_cols = []
    for _col in df.columns:
        if _col != 'period' and (not _col.startswith(col_name)) and _col != 'Markets':
            unwanted_cols.append(_col)
    print("Unwanted cols are: ")
    print(unwanted_cols)
    df = df.drop(columns=unwanted_cols)
    return df


def main(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Put your main logic here.

    Help:
        To get pandas dataframe of upstream nodes.
        data_frame = get_pandas_df("<upstream_node_name>")

        Example: data_frame = get_pandas_df("S3")

    Return:
        output_data_frame {pandas.DataFrame}
        This data frame will be transferred to downstream nodes.
    """
    # read dataframes
    df = get_pandas_df("CSV")
    df = sanitize_column_names(df)
    df_sales = df
    df_gr_vol = df
    df_gr_val = df

    print("remove unwanted cols for individual melts")
    df = remove_unwanted_cols(df, 'value_offtake_000_rs__')
    df_sales = remove_unwanted_cols(df_sales, 'sales_volume__volume_litres__')
    df_gr_vol = remove_unwanted_cols(df_gr_vol, 'gr_vol_ya')
    df_gr_val = remove_unwanted_cols(df_gr_val, 'gr_val_ya')

    df = get_first_row_as_header(df)
    df_sales = get_first_row_as_header(df_sales)
    df_gr_vol = get_first_row_as_header(df_gr_vol)
    df_gr_val = get_first_row_as_header(df_gr_val)

    print("melting dataframes")
    table_columns = df.columns
    df = pd.melt(
        df, id_vars=table_columns[:last_correct_constant+1],
        value_vars=table_columns[last_correct_constant+1:], var_name='period',
        value_name='value_offtake_000_rs__')
    df = df[(df["Markets"] != '')]


    table_columns = df_sales.columns
    df_sales = pd.melt(
        df_sales, id_vars=table_columns[:last_correct_constant+1],
        value_vars=table_columns[last_correct_constant+1:], var_name='period',
        value_name='sales_volume__volume_litres__')
    df_sales = df_sales[(df_sales["Markets"] != '')]
    df_sales = remove_cols_for_join(df_sales, 'sales_volume__volume_litres__')


    table_columns = df_gr_vol.columns
    df_gr_vol = pd.melt(
        df_gr_vol, id_vars=table_columns[:last_correct_constant+1],
        value_vars=table_columns[last_correct_constant+1:], var_name='period',
        value_name='gr_vol_ya')
    df_gr_vol = df_gr_vol[(df_gr_vol["Markets"] != '')]
    df_gr_vol = remove_cols_for_join(df_gr_vol, 'gr_vol_ya')

    table_columns = df_gr_val.columns
    df_gr_val = pd.melt(
        df_gr_val, id_vars=table_columns[:last_correct_constant+1],
        value_vars=table_columns[last_correct_constant+1:], var_name='period',
        value_name='gr_val_ya')
    df_gr_val = df_gr_val[(df_gr_val["Markets"] != '')]
    df_gr_val = remove_cols_for_join(df_gr_val, 'gr_val_ya')

    print("Before merge: ")
    for _col in df.columns :
        print(_col)
    print("==================")
    for _col in df_sales.columns :
        print(_col)

    df = pd.merge(df, df_sales, on=['Markets', 'period'])
    df = pd.merge(df, df_gr_val, on=['Markets', 'period'])
    df = pd.merge(df, df_gr_vol, on=['Markets', 'period'])
    df = sanitize_column_names(df)
    return df
```

I expect this code to run with efficiently using memory and cpu. My current memory is set for 32GB and 10CPU cores.

The data contains 14 rows and 637 columns which I transform in an aforementioned way.

Comment: can you post your deployment YAML?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov
https://pastebin.com/eTWQhuCn

Comment: you said you pod does not get restarted and at the same time you write about system OOM. Does that mean that sometimes your pod crash with OOM?

Comment: When I describe the node, it states Warning -> System OOM encountered. However, get pods shows that the pod is up and running without any restart. Also, airflow's webserver is 503 for a min or two.
@VasilyAngapov

Comment: That basically means that your pod eats all the memory of the node and gets killed by OOM. Number of restarts equal to zero does not tell the full story as it is counted only from last image update. You can define resource limits for your pod, but i don't think it may help. Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Comment: @VasilyAngapov
But I monitored with grafana and cloudwatch, it is when CPU utilization reaches 100% that the script stops, memory used is anyways less than 500MB. As for the doc, I have read it and then cross checked my configurations, in which I don't state any limit. This kubernetes cluster is running on a machine which has 4CPU cores and 8GB memory, my airflow has only one worker though, capable of using this much mem and cpu cores.

Comment: try to put some reasonable cpu limit like 3.5 cpu. Strange thing may happen when cpu pressure is in place. You need to put more control over cpu time.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov, thats what i said, there is no cpu limit. are you suggesting to put some?

Comment: Yeah, you may try.

Comment: If you are using the `KubernetesExecutor` in Airflow, don't forget you can set pod/container fields at a task/Operator level with `executor_config` (Reference: [baseoperator.py#L198](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L198)).